Uniqueness of common $ \mathbb Z _ n $-roots of polynomials in $ \mathbb Z [ x ] $ from linearity of their GCD
$ \def \Z {\mathbb Z} $EDIT: In the statement of the problem, the "every $ n \in \Z _ + $" is now changed to "all but finitely many $ n \in \Z _ + $". The unnecessary previous complication in notation is also removed. Thanks to Greg Martin for his kind comments.


Let $ p _ 1 ( x ) , \dots , p _ k ( x ) \in \Z [ x ] $ and $ p ( x ) = \gcd \bigl ( p _ 1 ( x ) , \dots , p _ k ( x ) \bigr ) $. Assume that there are $ a , b \in \Z $ such that $ \gcd ( a , b ) = 1 $ and $ p ( x ) = a x + b $. Can it be proven that for all but finitely many $ n \in \Z _ + $, the polynomials $ p _ 1 ( x ) $, $ \dots $ and $ p _ k ( x ) $ have at most a single common root in $ \Z _ n $?

This question can be considered as the converse of (a generalization of) one of my previous posts: "A polynomial with unique root in every $ \Z _ n $". Following the lines in the answer by Eric Wofsey, one can show that if for every $ n \in \Z _ + $, the polynomials $ p _ 1 ( x ) $, $ \dots $ and $ p _ k ( x ) $ have at most one common root in $ \Z _ n $, then $ p ( x ) $ must be of the form $ a x + b $ for some $ a , b \in \Z $ with $ \gcd ( a , b ) = 1 $.
For this problem, I could show that the statement must hold for infinitely many positive integers $ n $. To see this, note that Bézout's identity holds for univariate polynomials with coefficients from the field of rational numbers. Therefore, there are $ m \in \Z _ + $ and $ q _ 1 ( x ) , \dots , q _ k ( x ) \in \Z [ x ] $ such that $ \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ k p _ i ( x ) q _ i ( x ) = m p ( x ) $. Therefore, for every $ c \in \Z $ such that $ c \bmod n $ is a common $ \Z _ n $-root of $ p _ 1 ( x ) $, $ \dots $ and $ p _ k ( x ) $, we have $ m ( a c + b ) \equiv 0 \pmod n $. There are the following two sets of positive integers $ n $ for which we can prove the statement; one in which there is no common root modulo $ n $, and one in which there is a unique one. The second set is certainly infinite.

Let $ n ' = \frac n { \gcd ( n , m ) } $ and $ d = \gcd ( a , n ' ) $. Assume that $ m $ is not divisible by $ n $, and $ d \ne 1 $. from $ m ( a c + b ) \equiv 0 \pmod n $ we get $ a c + b \equiv 0 \pmod { n ' } $. Such $ c $ cannot exist, as we must have $ a c + b \equiv 0 \pmod d $, while we know that $ a c \equiv 0 \pmod d $, and at the same time $ b \not \equiv 0 \pmod d $, since $ \gcd ( a , b ) = 1 $.
Assume that $ \gcd ( m , n ) = 1 $ and $ \gcd ( a , n ) = 1 $. Then $ m ( a c + b ) \equiv 0 \pmod n $ implies $ a c + b \equiv 0 \pmod n $, and thus $ c \equiv - b \cdot a ^ { \phi ( n ) - 1 } \pmod n $, where $ \phi $ is Euler's totient function.

Note that in case $ n $ is a divisor of $ m $, $ \sum _ { i = 1 } ^ k p _ i ( x ) q _ i ( x ) $ will be congruent modulo $ n $ to the zero polynomial in $ \Z [ x ] $, and one cannot get any information about the common $ \Z _ n $-roots of $ p _ 1 ( x ) $, $ \dots $ and $ p _ k ( x ) $ from an argument similar to the one above. In the case where $ m $ is not divisible by $ n $ and $ d = 1 $, one can get $ c \equiv - b \cdot a ^ { \phi ( n ' ) - 1 } \pmod { n ' } $; but this leaves open the possibility of multiple common roots modulo $ n $.
So the question is whether one can prove the statement for those positive integers $ n $ that are not dealt with in the above argument, and in case there are examples in which the statement does not hold for all $ n $, whether there is a nice characterization of the set of those $ n $ for which the statement holds.

If I may offer some constructive feedback: I would strongly recommend not using the notation $q^n(x)$ in this way. Not only does $q^n$ already have a meaning that will be hard for readers to override, but it's completely unnecessary notation—it's already clear what it means for $q(x)\in Bbb Z[x]$ to be considered a polynomial over $\Bbb Z_n$ and have factorizations/roots there.

Given $k\ge2$, isn't $p_j(x) = (x+1)(x+kj)$ a counterexample for every $n$ dividing $k$?

@GregMartin You're right that in this question, it's completely unnecessary to make a distinction between $q$ and $q^n$; when we are only interested in their roots in $\Bbb Z_n$, they behave exactly the same. But in the context from which the question comes, the difference did matter, as for example when $p(x)=x$ and $q(x)=x+n$, $p$ and $q$ are different objects (even when we want to only look at their $\Bbb Z_n$-roots), while $p^n$ and $q^n$ are the same object. As this aspect of the polynomials themselves is irrelevant here, I'll edit the post and remove it.

@GregMartin About the example you provided, you're right; it indeed is a counterexample, which I hadn't come up with on my own. The question I asked was exactly intended to examine whether there could exist such counterexamples. I suppose now that this counterexample is known to exist, the question would be whether on can always prove the statement for all but finitely many positive integers $n$. I'll edit the post accordingly. And I promise, this would be the final version of the question.
